# Why can't I call my name space within jQuery(document).ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

I'm creating namespaces for my project and I want to call a function within `jQuery(document).ready()`.

Using [the self encapsulated jQuery namespace structure](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-function-namespacing-plain-english/) I'm able to make the example work.
But once I move `MYNAMESPACE.myFunction();`inside `jQuery(document).ready()`, it's not working any more.

This is probably because of some jQuery logic that I don't understand. Can anyone push me in the right direction please? [Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spstieng/Br5jp/2/).

Code:

```
//HTML
<div class="test"> test </div> 

//JS
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if($('.test').text().length > 0){            
        MYNAMESPACE.myFunction(); //function call
    }

});

;var MYNAMESPACE = {};
;(function($) {

    MYNAMESPACE = {
        myFunction: function()
        {
            $('.test').text('Text changed');
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
//  MYNAMESPACE.myFunction(); //<-- This works
```

Comment: why are you redefining `MYNAMESPACE`?

Comment: @DanielA.White, if you don't declare the namespace in the outer scope, you will get `ReferenceError: MYNAMESPACE is not defined’.`. You can test that yourself. PS. I'm just following the tutorial ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your fiddle is executed on window.load. Which means that the document is ready when you make that call and jQuery synchronously executes the callback. At that point, you haven't defined `MYNAMESPACE`.

It works if you specify that you don't want the code to execute on window.load: http://jsfiddle.net/baT47/

Or if you define `MYNAMESPACE` first: http://jsfiddle.net/c8L7c/

```
;var MYNAMESPACE = {};

;(function($) {

    MYNAMESPACE = {
        myFunction: function()
        {
            $('.test').text('Text changed');
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
//  MYNAMESPACE.myFunction(); //function call

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if($('.test').text().length > 0){            
        MYNAMESPACE.myFunction(); //function call
    }

});
```

Comment: Yeah, why is the order important? I didn't think js function / jQuery was procedural.

Comment: @steven _The code in your fiddle is executed on window.load._

Comment: It is important here, because when you call `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` after the document.ready event has already fired, the callback is executed synchronously, so the `MYNAMESPACE.myFunction()` bit is executed before the `MYNAMESPACE = { myFunction: ...` bit.